# Update NSView Background color in fullscreen

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview

I want to set a background color to a view and as of now I have subclassed that view in Xib and in `drawRect` method I am setting the color.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [[NSColor blackColor] setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```

Am using `[self.view enterFullScreenMode:screen withOptions:nil];` to show the view(which contains an image) in fullscreen. But when view is in fullscreen it shows a default gray background instead of black color. How can I set the background to black ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your methods calling? Put a NSLog to make sure.

If it is, then delete the line `[super drawRect:dirtyRect];`

Comment: Turns out it was due to some problems in nib. It was not subclassed. Just deleted the nib and did it again.